# Get Object nested structure as string path

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following set of classes. There are two things I would like to achieve.

1. Get the string representation of the path of the current property. For example totalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset.Path should return "TotalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset"
2. Given a path "TotalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset" and a value "100", I want to use the path to retrieve the property and change its value.

Code Example:

```
public abstract class Field
{
    private string _path = string.Empty;

    public double Value {get;set;}

    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            //Code probably goes here
            throw new NotImplementedException();

        }
        protected set { _path = value; }
    }
}

public sealed class TotalAsset : Field
{
    public TotalAsset(BuildingAsset buildingAsset)
    {
        Path = "TotalAsset";
        BuildingAsset = buildingAsset;
    }

    public BuildingAsset BuildingAsset { get; private set; }
}

public sealed class BuildingAsset : Field
{
    public HistoricalBuildingAsset HistoricalBuildingAsset { get; private set; }
    public BuildingAsset(HistoricalBuildingAsset historicalBuildingAsset)
    {
        Path = "BuildingAsset";
        this.HistoricalBuildingAsset = historicalBuildingAsset;
    }
}

public sealed class HistoricalBuildingAsset : Field
{

    public HistoricalBuildingAsset()
    {
        Path = "HistoricalBuildingAsset";
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestPath
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MethodTestPath()
    {
        var historicalBuildingAsset = new HistoricalBuildingAsset();
        var buildingAsset = new BuildingAsset(historicalBuildingAsset);
        var totalAsset = new TotalAsset(buildingAsset);

        Assert.AreEqual("TotalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset", totalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset.Path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you need this and in what context. Are you sure you need to be able to get a `Path` to an arbitrary object, can such an object not exist as the property of multiple other objects? A collection element doesn't and shouldn't know its position in said collection and frankly your `Path` solution also doesn't seem maintainable. You could borrow C# syntax for things, like `foo.SomeCollection[5].Bar`, where you'll have to use string parsing and reflection to retrieve `Bar`.

Comment: this seem to be a good candidate for reflection too

Comment: After your edit: so you don't need to get the path given an arbitrary object, you only want to find a property based on a string path?

Comment: What Hunter may be trying to do is to create something like nested namespaces in hierarchies of physical objects that only partially correspond to hierarchies of physical inclusion.  I.e. like "Car.LeftWheel.Diameter".

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't do this with reflection instead of manually specifying things.  You could then recursively get the path of things by descending your object graph.

Comment: Given a path, I can use reflection and recursion to modify the value in the path. However, first, I need to create a path. I am evaluating Lambda Expressions at the moment, which could possible solve the first part of my problem. I found a sample here. http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/get-name-of-nested-property-as-string-value/

Comment: You can also use reflection to build the path in the first place.  Look at the type definition, get the name, descend the type, and so on until you get down as low as you want to go.

Comment: I would post an example but I think Matias has already given you one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this be easily solved using polymorphism?

Based on your question, it seems like your `Path` property has an inmutable value, thus you should be able to solve your issue like the following code:

```
public class A 
{
     public virtual string Path
     {
         get { return "A"; }
     }
}

public class B : A 
{
     public override string Path
     { 
         get { return base.Path + ".B"; }
     }
}

public class C : B 
{
     public override string Path
     { 
         get { return base.Path + ".C"; }
     }
}

A a = new A();
Console.WriteLine(a.Path); // Prints "A"

B b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(b.Path); // Prints "A.B"

C c = new C();
Console.WriteLine(c.Path); // Prints "A.B.C"
```

### Update v1.1: Recursive approach (now includes getting a property value and setting a property value by a given object path)

Because you want to leave your model *as is* and go with the composition way, this is the piece of "magic" to dynamically get the whole path. Note that I've required a new `FullPath` property in order to avoid an infinite loop during path calculation ([you can also try it in a DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X4fZ0x)):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public abstract class Field
{
    public double Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Path
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public string FullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return BuildPath(this);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively-builds a dot-separated full path of associated fields
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field">Optional, it's a reference to current associated field </param>
    /// <param name="path">Optional, provided when this method enters to the first associated </param>
    /// <returns>The whole dot-separated full path of associations to Field</returns>
    private string BuildPath(Field field, string path = "")
    {
        // Top-level path won't start with dot
        if (path != string.Empty)
        {
            path += '.';
        }

        path += field.Path;

        // This will look for a property which is of type Field
        PropertyInfo fieldProperty = field.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                                                .SingleOrDefault(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Field)));

        // If current field has a property of type Field...
        if (fieldProperty != null)
        {
            // ...we'll get its value and we'll start a recursion to find the next Field.Path
            path = BuildPath((Field)fieldProperty.GetValue(field, null), path);
        }

        return path;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively sets a value to an associated field property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The whole path to the property</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to set</param>
    /// <param name="associatedField">Optional, it's a reference to current associated field</param>
    public void SetByPath(string path, object value, Field associatedField = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path.Trim()))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be null or empty");
        }

        string[] pathParts = path.Split('.');

        if (associatedField == null)
        {
            associatedField = this;
        }

        // This will look for a property which is of type Field
        PropertyInfo property = associatedField.GetType().GetProperty(pathParts[0], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("A property in the path wasn't found", "path");
        }

        object propertyValue = property.GetValue(associatedField, null);

        // If property value isn't a Field, then it's the last part in the path 
        // and it's the property to set
        if (!propertyValue.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Field)))
        {
            property.SetValue(associatedField, value);
        }
        else
        {
            // ... otherwise, we navigate to the next associated field, removing the first
            // part in the path, so the next call will look for the next property...
            SetByPath(string.Join(".", pathParts.Skip(1)), value, (Field)propertyValue);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursively gets a value from an associated field property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The whole path to the property</param>
    /// <param name="associatedField">Optional, it's a reference to current associated field</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the property from which the value is going to be obtained</typeparam>
    public T GetByPath<T>(string path, Field associatedField = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path.Trim()))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path cannot be null or empty");
        }

        string[] pathParts = path.Split('.');

        if (associatedField == null)
        {
            associatedField = this;
        }

        // This will look for a property which is of type Field
        PropertyInfo property = associatedField.GetType().GetProperty(pathParts[0], BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("A property in the path wasn't found", "path");
        }

        object propertyValue = property.GetValue(associatedField, null);

        // If property value isn't a Field, then it's the last part in the path 
        // and it's the property to set
        if (!propertyValue.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Field)))
        {
            return (T)property.GetValue(associatedField, null);
        }
        else
        {
            // ... otherwise, we navigate to the next associated field, removing the first
            // part in the path, so the next call will look for the next property...
            return GetByPath<T>(string.Join(".", pathParts.Skip(1)), (Field)propertyValue);
        }
    }
}

public sealed class TotalAsset : Field
{
    public TotalAsset(BuildingAsset buildingAsset)
    {
        Path = "TotalAsset";
        BuildingAsset = buildingAsset;
    }

    public BuildingAsset BuildingAsset
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public sealed class BuildingAsset : Field
{
    public HistoricalBuildingAsset HistoricalBuildingAsset
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public BuildingAsset(HistoricalBuildingAsset historicalBuildingAsset)
    {
        Path = "BuildingAsset";
        this.HistoricalBuildingAsset = historicalBuildingAsset;
    }
}

public sealed class HistoricalBuildingAsset : Field
{
    public HistoricalBuildingAsset()
    {
        Path = "HistoricalBuildingAsset";
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TotalAsset total = new TotalAsset(new BuildingAsset(new HistoricalBuildingAsset()));

        // Prints "TotalAsset.BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset"
        Console.WriteLine(total.FullPath);

        total.SetByPath("BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset.Age", 300);

        // Prints "300" as expected!
        Console.WriteLine(total.GetByPath<int>("BuildingAsset.HistoricalBuildingAsset.Age"));
    }
}
```

Comment: But my model uses composition.

Comment: @Hunter I've re-updated it to also include a solution to set a property by a given path!

Answer (score 0):

You can re-use the existing .net framework Binding pattern and codebase. Your description of what you want to do sounds mightily like MVVM binding to me. The use of Binding in WPF is explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx.

Using System.Windows.Data.Binding gives you an extensible framework for getting data into and out of object graphs using relative and absolute string paths to nominate the class members and collection indexes.